# CFG PL for L=\{a^ib^j \mid j = i^2\}

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

[where i got it from](https://youtu.be/c1ph0MgYQ-0). This was weird so I wanted to try it myself because they way he did it seemed wrong. So this is my attempt is it correct?

I did not add the basic parts of the pumping lemma proof but just did the hard part, is it correct?

$L=\{a^ib^j \mid j = i^2\}$, ab, aabbbb

$z = a^nb^n$

Case one: v and x only contain a's

set i = 69, the number of a's is more than the number of b's

Case two: v and x only contains b's

set i = 69, the number of b's is not equal to $i^2$

Case three: v and x contains a's and b's

set i = 69 , the number of a's and b's do not equal $i^2$